# How to force npm to use global eslint without removing local eslint?

Tags: npm, eslint

I have local eslint installed for a react project but I want to run a different eslint from the global eslint (different version and plugins), is there a `--global` flag or some trick that would enable me to do so or must I include the absolute path to the global eslint?

Comment: i think if you uninstall local package and run app after that install local again it will keep using global package.